# How to rotate son of instance back to the world? (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

Could you please tell me how I can create a "support" for a sphere, where lines will shoot out of it in the normal direction, then go straight down?
I cannot make this work, they will still shoot in the normal direction.
[image: Example, the long lines is two lines]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can project end points of curve to a plane using `RayCast Node`

[image]

Comment: Excellent!!! Thank you!